# mtimes operator for multiplication in matlab wrong behavior

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

If we define a variable `a` in matlab as `a = [1 2]` then `a` is represented as a matrix with dimensions `1x2 double` . Now if we define a variable `b` in matlab as `b = 3` then `b` is represented as a matrix with dimensions `1x1 double`. 
Now if we use the standard multiplication operator "mtimes" `a*b` the result is `[3 6]`. I am expecting it to throw an error that dimensions don't agree but it is working, although if we try `[1 2]*[3 4]` it gives a dimension doesn't agree error. Why doesn't matlab throw an error in the first case when doing `a*b`.

Thanks.

Comment: See also ["Do scalars commute across matrices?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214224/do-scalars-commute-across-matrices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimensions 1x1 means a scalar. Thus you have the product between a scalar and a matrix.